# Extracting lists from tuple with a condition

Tags: python, list, tuples

I've been trying to extracting from this tuples
`E=tuple([random.randint(0,10) for x in range(10)])` 
Let's say the result is `(3,4,5,0,0,3,4,2,2,4)` .

I want to extract from this tuple lists of numbers is ascending order without sorting the tuple or anything.
Example : `[[3,4,5],[0,0,3,4],[2,2,4]]`

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: I couldn't figure out from where should I start. That's why I posted the question.

Comment: @BouhaaCode How you can have the result `3450034224` from `E=[random.randint(0,10) for x in range(N)]`? `E` should be a `list`, not a string.

Comment: @AndrejKesely actually it's a tuple sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom function (generator in my example) to group ascending elements:

```py
def get_ascending(itr):
    lst = []
    for v in itr:
        if not lst:
            lst = [v]
        elif v < lst[-1]:
            yield lst
            lst = [v]
        else:
            lst.append(v)
    yield lst


E = 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4
print(list(get_ascending(E)))
```

Prints:

```py
[[3, 4, 5], [0, 0, 3, 4], [2, 2, 4]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment and the solution provided. Is it possible to make it using a List comprehension ?

Comment: @BouhaaCode With list-comprehension it will be probably very messy, unreadable code (when possible at all..). I don't recommend list-comprehension in this situation.